# Redefinition of Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have only just started learning C++ yesterday, so im completely new, although I came over from Java.
I am making a game as my first small project.
I want to have my player class separate from the main file.
I have my header file and cpp file made up like this:

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Entity {
    public:
        Entity(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow& win) : window(win) {}
        void tick();
        void render();
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
        float velX;
        float velY;
        sf::RenderWindow& window;
        bool keys[264] = {};
};
```

C++:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "headers/Entity.h"

using namespace sf;

Texture texture;
Sprite sprite;

Entity::Entity(int x, int y, RenderWindow& win) : window(win) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->velX = 0;
    this->velY = 0;
    this->window = win;


    texture.loadFromFile("../res/img/test.png");
    sprite(texture);
}

void Entity::tick() {

    // movement
}

void Entity::render() {
    this->window.draw(sprite);
}
```

But in the cpp file the constructor keeps saying:

```
redefinition of 'Entity::Entity(int, int, sf::RenderWindow&)'
```

I have searched up many times how to fix this but I can't find anything that works, because this issue carries on no matter what I try. I would prefer the theory aswell as I am brand new with any answer.
Thank You.

Comment: A warning. Because the philosophies behind the language designs of Java and C++ are so wildly different you have to take care that the similarities between the languages do not lull you into writing C++ code the way you would Java code. They may have a similar look, but the feel is very different.

Comment: `this->window = win;` is not doing anything useful. You already initialized the `window` reference in the member-initializer-list ( `: window(win)`). What the line in question is trying to do is to assign the window to itself (not reassign the reference, which is impossible).

Comment: Warning: A reference cannot be reseated. Once a reference is initialized to refer to a particular object it cannot be changed to a refer to a different object. That means `sf::RenderWindow& window;` will make it impossible to properly assign `Entities`  (You can't `Entity a (params), b(params); a = b;`). The resulting error messages if someone tries can be nigh-inscrutable. I recommend adding `Entity& operator=(const Entity&) = delete;` to disable the assignment operator. This often results in easier-to-understand diagnostic messages.

Comment: @walnut thanks, I didn't notice that I saw about that on another post and must of forgot to remove it.

Comment: @user4581301 which file do I add this to, I presume it will be the header file.

Comment: It goes in the `public` section of the class definition in the header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header is providing a implementation / definition of your constructor:

```
    Entity(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow& win) : window(win) {}
```

And so is your source file.

Change the header to just contain the declaration:

```
    Entity(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow& win);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I did need to also remove the `this->window  = win;` code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailings `{}` and the link to the super class ctor  in the declaration file for the constructor, ie :

```
class Entity {
  public:
    Entity(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow& win);
    void tick();
```

With `{}` and `: window(win)` it is no more a declaration but a definition, thus you will have two definitions: one in the header and one in the source...

Remove one of them.

Comment: This simply will not compile. Did you intend to also remove `: window(win)`?

Comment: @alterigel sure I forgot doing it.